# Implicit "SELECT" in SPARQL?

Tags: java, sparql, jena, apache-jena

so I want to rewrite some SPARQL queries of some old code (which is not from me) with the SPARQL QueryBuilder from the Jena library. The query looks like this:

```sql
    SELECT ?s ?p ?o {
        {   
            ?s ?p ?o. 
            <http://www.test.org/node1> ?p ?o. 
            FILTER (str(?s) = "http://www.test.org/node1").
        } 
        UNION {
            ?s ?p ?o. 
            ?s ?p <http://www.test.org/node1>. 
            FILTER (str(?o) = "http://www.test.org/node1"). 
            FILTER(!regex(str(?p),"http://www.test.org/vocab#someProperty", "i"))
        }
}
```

My problem is now that if you want to add a "Union" or "Subquery" in this library you have to pass down another `SelectBuilder` which would make the subquery then start with a "SELECT" and not with the ?s ?p ?o statement like above. Am I missing some implicit SPARQL concept or is this basically a `SELECT *` in the subquery/union making the query look like:

```sql
SELECT ?s ?p ?o {
        {   
            SELECT * {
                ?s ?p ?o. 
                <http://www.test.org/node1> ?p ?o. 
                FILTER (str(?s) = "http://www.test.org/node1").
            }   
        } 
        UNION {
            SELECT * {          
                ?s ?p ?o. 
                ?s ?p <http://www.test.org/node1>. 
                FILTER (str(?o) = "http://www.test.org/node1"). 
                FILTER(!regex(str(?p),"http://www.test.org/vocab#someProperty", "i"))
            }   
        }
}
```

Comment: Looks like [JENA-971](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JENA-971)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yeah i actually had this problem aswell but solved it by just adding a "subquery" with another SelectBuilder instead of adding my conditions to the "top level" SelectBuilder. My question is actually simpler, but i probably did not phrase it good. So here more clearly worded: Is the upper query the same as the bottom query.

Comment: The queries have the same effect.  Inner `SELECT *` (and no modifiers) is roughly the same as writing another level of `{}`.

Comment: Okay thank you, that's all i wanted to know